# How to ivoke update_feed() from /data_feeds/google_merchand.py/ every time when load url in saleor?

Tags: python, django, saleor

I need to invoke update_feed() on  url - *`localhost:8000/feeds/google_merchand.py/`*. `update_feed()` generates and saves file in directory.

There's a function `get_feed_file_url()`:

```
def get_feed_file_url():
    return default_storage.url(FILE_PATH)
```

, and it's invoked on *`localhost:8000/feeds/google/`* , and I tried to add `update_feed()` to this function. The problem is this function seems not to be call every time. In urls.py I found this line:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'google/$', RedirectView.as_view(
        get_redirect_url=get_feed_file_url, permanent=True), name='google-feed')]
```

and `RedirectView` redirect me directly to the generated file, but it sometimes does and doesn't invoke `get_feed_file_url`. `get_feed_file_url` is invoked for a few first times, but after a few times it stops invoke `get_feed_file_url`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to look, a browser caches url. All you have to do is clear browsing history on browser.